I want to convert HTML data to PDF, having that PDF should have header(HTML) and footer(HTML) on all pages
I have tried several method in .Net Core to pass a HTML data which returns a PDF file with header(HTML) and footer(HTML) added on all pages. But somehow not getting proper working solution for same.
Out of many, one code I have given below is giving all requirement except the header and footer on all pages and their positioning as well. I have used DinkToPDF here, please suggest code with any dll but it should work for .net core.

var htmlContent = $@"
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* CSS for fixed header */
        .header {{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }}
        /* CSS for fixed footer */
        .footer {{
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }}
        /* CSS for dynamic content */
        .content {{
             left: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-top: 50px; /* Adjust as per header height */
            padding-bottom: 50px; /* Adjust as per footer height */
        }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='header'>Fixed Header</div>
    <div class='content'>{request.DynamicContent}</div>
    <div class='footer'>Fixed Footer</div>
</body>
</html>";

                var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
                {
                    GlobalSettings = {
                    ColorMode = ColorMode.Color,
                    Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
                    PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
                },
                    Objects = {
                    new ObjectSettings() {
                        HtmlContent = htmlContent
                    }
                }
                };

                var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);
                return File(file, "application/pdf", "finalresult.pdf");


please supply some code, how do you convert from html to PDF? I use https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/

code already have that conversion part and its working fine also, just the header footer part is not working properly.

I've had any issued with the components a refered to. for us to get a better view of what is wrong you should include som of the code where you do the convertsion (C#)
